Error testing deeplinking Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=fooapp:///... flg=0x10000000 }
I'm trying to get deeplinking up and running. When I try to test with adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "fooapp://" I get the following error
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=fooapp:///... }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=fooApp:///... flg=0x10000000 }

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.fooapp">

            <!-- Main Launcher -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Deep Linking for fooapp:// -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <!-- For fooapp:// -->
                <data android:scheme="fooapp" android:host="" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


In two spots in this question, you have fooapp as the scheme. In others, you have fooApp (capital A). Is that intentional?

Those are typos. I removed my app name for SO, but good point on case. Just to confirm, are you referring to  <data android:scheme="fooapp" android:host="" />

Your title also has fooApp, as does the error message. Part of the reason I asked is because I suspect that schemes are case-sensitive.

Thanks, I checked the cases in my actual code and it matches. I also updated the title.
